# Javascript: Overriding Map function

Tags: javascript

I need to have an object called Map() but it appears there is some function in JavaScript with the same name and when I override it I'm unable to use console (or maybe it's just Opera browser thing). What would be the best way around it? I know I could just use some namespace, but Map is kinda my namespace by itself, so it'd be just too chaotic.

@edit: So I came across this [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) and I think it may be the best way to use it in my case. Thanks for all the comments anyway.

Comment: you can override it, if you must... honestly, just change the name of your 'namespace' & don't fuss.

Comment: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a js type.  The best way is to not use the same name.

Comment: "but Map is kinda my namespace by itself" please stick to the coding conventions in JS. Only classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: If Map is your namespace then just modify it to include a vendor name so that collisions are less likely. Some suggestions: `LeszekMap, WeisnerMap, PotatoMap, WimbleMap, GlumbouskiMap, FroodleMap, ScritchMap, NapMap, FizzleMap, WontonMap, EntupleMap`.

Comment: @Thomas Whose convention is that? I always use uppercase first letter for namespaces, and all caps for constants.

Comment: @Paulpro, actually I don't know it anymore. That's how i've learned it years ago, and it's one of these things you learn once and then stick to it. I assume that's no satisfying answer, sry. *(btw. same here for constants)*

Comment: FWIW, I usually use a similar convention as @Thomas (i.e. capitalizing classes, uppercasing constants, and camel casing variables/instances)

Comment: @Martin I think what I use is actually quite similar to that. I do UpperCamelCase for classes (or functions that are meant to be used as constructors) and camelCase properties of objects, but I use `lowercase_with_underscores` for normal variables, `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` for constants (whether they are a property of an object or not), and UpperCamelCase for namespaces (I only ever use one root namespace and properties of that object may also be UpperCamelCase subnamespaces).

Comment: @LeszekWiesner, what exactly is your use-case? Maybe you can use a different namespace/name and inject it for example into an IIFE. This way you can use whatever *(valid)* name you want in your code, and don't have collisions in the global namespace. `(function(Map){ /* ... */ })( MyOwnMap );`

Answer (score 3):

I would say namespace it or create a name other than Map. [It's attached to most browser's `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It would be dangerous to rename it in case it's a dependency of any package your codebase is using.